# My (Windows 10 Home) computer shuts down and reboots randomly; no bluescreen

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, crash, reboot

My PC (running Windows 10 Home) with Corsair GS600 power supply and G6T motherboard shuts down randomly and try reboot and sometime shutdown again before Windows booted yet. And if it started and I try shutdown it it will reboot instead and stop only if I put power supply off.

Comment: Check event log

Comment: If your event log shows Event 6008, then the PC is shutting down from a physical cause (see my Answer).  If it weren't for the PC rebooting before Windows completes booting, it might have been a software issue.  For future Questions, it's worth mentioning if the machine worked properly in the past, when it stopped working properly, and any changes that happened around the time it stopped working.  For instance, if you added multiple high-draw graphics cards then the PSU might be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it will sometimes reboot before Windows is done booting makes me think several possibilities :  the power supply is overloaded (count your component wattage and get a high-capacity PSU), the power utility is not supplying constant power (use a UPS), or one or more cables is loose (unseat and reseat all cables both ends, starting from the wall, PSU, components).  It's also possible that something is physically broken, leading to flexing and sometimes-disconnecting components.